# Vioplot in r Version 1.4.1717

Tags: r, violin-plot

I have used `vioplot()` before for my coding but I guess since I have updated my RStudio it is not being recognized anymore. It asks me to do `library(sm)` but that doesn't solve anything either. Is there anything I can do about it? The code below is what I am getting:

```
vioplot(SOCsplit5$`1`[,3:12], main="Cluster 1", ylim=c(0,100))
Error in vioplot(SOCsplit5$`1`[, 3:12], main = "Cluster 1", ylim = c(0,  : 
  could not find function "vioplot"
```

```
library(vioplot)
Error: package ‘sm’ could not be loaded
```

```
library(sm)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sm’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details: call: fun(libname, pkgname) error: X11 library is missing: install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org
```

Comment: You need to install package `sm`. Usually it is installed automatically when you install `vioplot`. You also need package `zoo` so you might want to install that as well if it is not already installed. I'm not sure where you get version 1.4.1717. The current version is 0.3.7. See [Package viplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vioplot/index.html).

Comment: 1.4.1717 sounds like an rstudio version (which is irrelevant 99% of the time).   Have you attempted to do what the error told you to do, i.e. "install XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org" ?

Comment: @BenBolker yes I did. But it seems there is no such a thing.

Comment: Did you try https://www.xquartz.org/ ?

Comment: Yes I tried that one too. Tried all the path